# Why required rule not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-4

When I add required rule the validation pass even in the post data not contain (name), but if I have other rules like (valid_email), the validation return false.

My Model:

```
namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class ProjectsMD extends Model
{

        protected $table                =   'projects';
        protected $primaryKey           =   'sid';
        protected $returnType           =   'App\Entities\Project';
        protected $allowedFields        =   ['name', 'description', 'location', 'area', 'client', 'stage'];
        protected $validationRules      =   [          
                                                'name'        =>      ['label' => 'App.name',         'rules'  =>  'required'],
                                            ];
        protected $useTimestamps        =   true;     
        
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function projectsCreate()
    {
        $projectsMD =   new \App\Models\ProjectsMD();
        
        if($projectsMD->validate($this->request->getPost()) === false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you inspected the request body `$this->request->getPost()` to confirm if the `name` value is truly empty?

Comment: yes I checked, no name at all

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72322703/edit) showing us the output of `$this->request->getPost()` then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the request body `$this->request->getPost()` to confirm if the `name` value is **not** an *empty array, empty string, null or false*?

[Available Rules](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#available-rules)

| Rule | Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `required` | No | Fails if the field is an empty array, empty string, null or false. |

Nonetheless, these validation rules should be sufficient.

`required|string|min_length[3]|max_length[120]`

*You may add additional validation rules depending on your specific requirements.*